# A Theorem from Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

Theorem 17.2 on page 94:
Let $Y$ be a subspace of X. Then a set A is closed if and only if it equals to the intersection of a closed set of $X$ with $Y$.

In his proof for one of the directions, he says 
assume $A$ is closed in $Y$. Then $Y-A$ is open in Y, so that by definition it equals to the intersection of an open set $U$ of $X$ with $Y$. The set $X-U$ is closed in $X$, and $A=Y\cap(X-U)$, so that $A$ equals the intersection of a closed set of $X$ with $Y$, as desired.

Could someone please explain why we have $A=Y\cap(X-U)$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Y-A = U \cap Y$$
Taking the relative complement of both sides with respect to $Y$ yields
$$A = Y - (U \cap Y) = Y \cap (X - U).$$

Comment: (+1) I was going to write the same answer but you did it first

Comment: (+1) Ditto ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Could you please explain how the second equality holds? I have $$Y-(U\cap Y)=Y\cap(X-(U\cap Y))=Y\cap((X-U)\cup(X-Y)).$$ I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @kmiyazaki $Y \cap (X-U) = (X \cap Y) - (U \cap Y) = Y - (U \cap Y)$.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you very much.